# How to use python timeit when passing variables to functions?

Tags: python, debugging, benchmarking

I'm struggling with this using timeit and was wondering if anyone had any tips

Basically I have a function(that I pass a value to) that I want to test the speed of and created this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer(superMegaIntenseFunction(10))
    print t.timeit(number=1)
```

but when I run it, I get weird errors like coming from the timeit module.:

```
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
```

If I run the function on its own, it works fine.  Its when I wrap it in the time it module, I get the errors(I have tried using double quotes and without..sameoutput).

any suggestions would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Make it a callable:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer(lambda: superMegaIntenseFunction(10))
    print(t.timeit(number=1))
```

Should work

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much.  I need to figure out what lambda does..seems like that made the difference.  Thanks Pablo

Comment: if only this were in the documentation somewhere

Comment: Oh but lambda adds some overhead, so not ideal for testing small things. `timeit 5*5` is 33 ns while `timeit (lambda: 5*5)()` is 233 ns.

Comment: This is perfect. I had a problem just calling `timeit` with the lambda (the script froze; the method I was measuring the execution time of is the `retrbinary` for downloading through FTP using the `ftplib`). Once I used the `Timer` object it suddenly worked like a charm. No idea what happened... :D

Answer (score 24):

`Timer(superMegaIntenseFunction(10))` means "call `superMegaIntenseFunction(10)`, then pass the result to `Timer`". That's clearly not what you want. `Timer` expects either a callable (just as it sounds: something that can be called, such as a function), or a string (so that it can interpret the contents of the string as Python code). `Timer` works by calling the callable-thing repeatedly and seeing how much time is taken.

`Timer(superMegaIntenseFunction)` would pass the type check, because `superMegaIntenseFunction` is callable. However, `Timer` wouldn't know what values to pass to `superMegaIntenseFunction`.

The simple way around this, of course, is to use a string with the code. We need to pass a 'setup' argument to the code, because the string is "interpreted as code" in a fresh context - it doesn't have access to the same `globals`, so you need to run another bit of code to make the definition available - see @oxtopus's answer.

With `lambda` (as in @Pablo's answer), we can bind the parameter `10` to a call to `superMegaIntenseFunction`. All that we're doing is creating another function, that takes no arguments, and calls `superMegaIntenseFunction` with `10`. It's just as if you'd used `def` to create another function like that, except that the new function doesn't get a name (because it doesn't need one).

Answer (score 20):

You should be passing a string. i.e.

```
t = Timer('superMegaIntenseFunction(10)','from __main__ import superMegaIntenseFunction')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer oxtopus! it doesn't work when I wrap it in quotes so its a string I get this error: NameError: global name 'superMegaIntenseFunction' is not defined. What else do you think I can try?

Comment: Corrected the answer to include the setup arg.

(http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be by using partial so that the function, 'superMegaIntenseFunction' is used as a callable (ie without the ()) in the timer or directly inside timeit.timeit. Using partial will pass the argument to the function when it will be call by the timer.

```
from functools import partial
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit(partial(superMegaIntenseFunction, 10), number=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

A note for future visitors. If you need to make it work in `pdb` debugger, and `superMegaIntenseFunction` is not in the global scope, you can make it work by adding to `globals`:

```
globals()['superMegaIntenseFunction'] = superMegaIntenseFunction
timeit.timeit(lambda: superMegaIntenseFunction(x))
```

> Note that the timing overhead is a little larger in this case because of the extra function calls. [[source]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer)