# Calling function using Timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I'm trying to time several things in python, including upload time to Amazon's S3 Cloud Storage, and am having a little trouble. I can time my hash, and a few other things, but not the upload. I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523767/how-to-use-python-timeit-when-passing-variables-to-functions) post would finally, get me there, but I can't seem to find salvation. Any help would be appreciated. Very new to python, thanks!

```
import timeit

accKey = r"xxxxxxxxxxx";
secKey = r"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

bucket_name = 'sweet_data'

c = boto.connect_s3(accKey, secKey)
b = c.get_bucket(bucket_name);
k = Key(b);

p = '/my/aws.path'
f = 'C:\\my.file'

def upload_data(p, f):
    k.key = p
    k.set_contents_from_filename(f)
    return

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: upload_data(p, f), "from aws_lib import upload_data; p=%r; f = %r" % (p,f))

# Just calling the function works fine
#upload_data(p, f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is heresy in the Python community, but I actually recommend *not* to use `timeit`, especially for something like this.  For your purposes, I believe it will be good enough (and possibly even better than `timeit`!) if you simply use `time.time()` to time things.  In other words, do something like

```
from time import time

t0 = time()
myfunc()
t1 = time()
print t1 - t0
```

Note that depending on your platform, you might want to try `time.clock()` instead (see Stack Overflow questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python)), and if you're on Python 3.3, then you have [better options](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html), due to [PEP 418](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/).

Comment: That is so much easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Coming from a .NET/C# background,  I found `timeit` very un-intuitive, especially with large functions and chunks of code. Just want to add that - I am currently on Python 3.8 and found the function `time.time_ns()` very useful. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line interface to `timeit`.

Just save your code as a module without the timing stuff. For example:

```
# file: test.py
data = range(5)
def foo(l):
    return sum(l)
```

Then you can run the timing code from the command line, like this:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import test;' 'test.foo(test.data)'
```

See also:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#examples

Comment: I'm sure that this works great, but it's a little more complicated than what I'm looking for. I was really looking to add a few lines to test parts of a function (module) instead of significantly altering my code. Thanks though, I'm sure that this will come in handy another time.