# NameError: name Timer is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, nameerror

I have a small python program written for python 2.7.3:

```
import time
def fun():
    print('Hi')
for i in range(3):
    Timer(i, fun).start()
```

When I run it, I get the error:

`NameError: name 'Timer' is not defined`

How can I find out which module supports this functionality?

Comment: You're looking for `timeit` module, aren't ya?

Comment: Try `from timeit import Timer`.

Comment: I've edited your question to pull out the opinion based question on Python 2 vs 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Timer` is in the `timeit` module, not `time`. And to call it like you want to, you would have to `from timeit import Timer`, not just `import timeit`. If you just declare `import timeit`, then you would have to write `timeit.Timer` instead of `Timer` everywhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error :

ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable

Comment: You need `lambda` function - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523767/how-to-use-python-timeit-when-passing-variables-to-functions

Comment: Then I get the error :

    AttributeError: 'Timer' object has no attribute 'start'

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module. You can use your existing code by replacing your current import:

```
from timeit import Timer
```