# Calling ftplib retrbinary() inside timeit using lambda freezes program

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, ftp-client, ftplib

I'm trying to gather some metrics regarding a network issue in a small LAN with SSH disconnecting occasionally and ping exhibiting huge delays (up to a minute instead of less than a second!).

Using `timeit` (I've read that it's a good way to check elapsed execution time when calling some code snippet) I try to download some data from a FTP server that also runs locally, measure the time and store it inside a log file.

```
from ftplib import FTP
from timeit import timeit
from datetime import datetime

ftp = FTP(host='10.0.0.8')
ftp.login(user='****', passw='****')
ftp.cwd('updates/')
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

# Get timestamp when the download starts
curr_t = datetime.now()

print('Download large file and measure the time')
file_big_t = timeit(lambda f=ftp: f.retrbinary('RETR update_big', open('/tmp/update_big', 'wb').write))

print('Download medium file and measure the time')
file_medium_t = timeit(lambda f=ftp: f.retrbinary('RETR file_medium ', open('/tmp/file_medium ', 'wb').write))

print('Download small file and measure the time')
file_small_t = timeit(lambda f=ftp: f.retrbinary('RETR update_small', open('/tmp/update_small', 'wb').write))

# Write timestamp and measured timings to file
# ...
```

If I call the `retrbinary(...)` without the `timeit` it works without any issues. However the code above results in the script freezing right after the first `timeit` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else wants to do what I've described in my question I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523810/1559401). For some reason passing the `lambda` directly to `timeit` results in the behaviour I've already mentioned. However if the **same** `lambda` is first passed to an instance of `timeit.Timer` and that that instance's `timeit()` function is called it works.

For the example above (let's take just `file_big_t`) I did

```
file_big_timer = Timer(lambda f=ftp: f.retrbinary('RETR update_big', open('/tmp/update_big', 'wb').write))
file_big_t = file_big_timer.timeit()
```